# Getting NSInternalInconsistencyException with FirebaseUI TableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebaseui

I have a tab bar controller with 3 views in it, each of them has a table view which gets populated from Firebase using the FirebaseUI for iOS library. I have the following problem:

I can compile and start the app, and also switch between the tabs, the tables show correctly populated. However when I continue randomly switching between the tabs, at some point I am always getting the `NSInternalInconsistencyException` with the reason:

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.

I did not have this issue when I had only a single table view. This comes up only now after I added the tab bar controller and 2 more table views.

My question is if I am missing something which needs to be taken care of when implementing multiple table views. Maybe someone has an idea what the cause of this might be.

All 3 table views get populated like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)

self.dataSource = self.notesTableView.bind(to: getQuery()) { tableView, indexPath, snap in

    let cell = self.notesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notesCellident", for: indexPath)
    let customCell = cell as! TextCell

    self.notesTableView.dataSource = self.dataSource
    self.notesTableView.delegate = self

    customCell.notesLabel.text = (snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "note").value as! NSString) as String

    return cell
}
}
```

Cheers

UPDATE:
I adapted the code above to the latest practices from the [quickstart example](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS). I am no longer getting this error.

Comment: You need to show some code, but this can occur when you update the array driving your tableview from a method that is asynchronously retrieving the data. Update a temporary array in your data receive closure and only update the actual array once you have all of the data.

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated my question. The FirebaseUI library takes care of keeping the table up to date, so there is no array involved from my side of things.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, can someone assist? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565906/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-when-populating-uitableview